# Cannot get value from bash shell output for pg_isready to a variable

Tags: bash, postgresql

I'm trying to get the value for the bash binary call `pg_isready` to a bash variable

I've tried the following in my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

haspostgresdb = ${pg_isready -h "ipaddress"}
echo $haspostgresbd

haspostgresdb = ${pg_isready -h ipaddress}
echo $haspostgresbd

haspostgresdb = ${pg_isready -hipaddress}
echo $haspostgresbd

haspostgresdb = ${pg_isready -h"ipaddress"}
echo $haspostgresbd
```

All return `bad substitution` as the response. **And I did some research and it looks like im doing it correctly**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) and *get rid of **blanks*** in the assign command:

```
haspostgresdb="$(pg_isready -h "ipaddress")"
```

Comment: get rid of blanks also

Comment: got it wokring now removed spaces